# Is possibile to hide elementis from ObservableCollection? Net MAUI

Tags: mvvm, maui, hide, observablecollection

I'm using MVVM and Ms Toolkit.

I'm showing a collection within a CollectionView, but I would like to hide *deleted* items (set by a flag on model).

This why I'm using a global "save" procedure in a tabs page but it would be nice to hide what I've deleted.

I've tried with `Where(p => p.deleted == false)` but:

1. won't work on ObservableColletion
2. return a IEnumerable

Searched Google & Docs already.

Comment: you would need to create a 2nd OC with those items filtered out and use that as the `ItemsSource`

Comment: Ufff. I've hoped there was "something" to operate on this collection :/ . Thanks

Comment: No, you cannot directly "hide" them from the collection, a collection essentially is a data container and has no UI-related responsibilities. You can either use a second collection that only contains filtered items, or you can add a property to the model class of the items in the collection and then bind the `IsVisible` property of the control inside the DataTemplate to that property of your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried with Where(p => p.deleted == false) but:
>
> 1.won't work on ObservableColletion
>
> 2.return a IEnumerable

Returning IEnumerable is not a problem, because it can be converted to list:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist?view=net-8.0

It will work on ObservableCollection, because you have constructor that takes list as parameter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-collections-objectmodel-observablecollection-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-list((-0)))

Also, even if anything of the above was not true, you can always:

1. Suppress notifications
2. Clear collection and add items.
3. Turn notifications on.

I do it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not showing your code, I'll provide a more generic answer.

You can add an `IsDeleted` property to your model class:

```cs
public partial class MyModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _name;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isDeleted;
}
```

Then, in your ViewModel you would keep your `ObservableCollection<MyModel>`:

```cs
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<MyModel> _myItems;
}
```

Finally, in your View, you would then bind to the `IsDeleted` property and use the [InvertedBoolConverter from the MCT](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/converters) to show or hide deleted items:

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <mct:InvertedBoolConverter x:Key="InvertedBoolConverter" />
</ContentPage.Resources>

<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MyModel">
            <Label
                Text="{Binding Name}"
                IsVisible="{Binding IsDeleted, Converter={StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Comment: Why this: [ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<MyModel> _myItems;?

Comment: @H.A.H. I don't understand the question. Do you mean that it should just be a normal property? Since the OP didn't show the relevant code, I just provided one way to do it. If the referenced collection changes, the binding needs to be updated, that's why I added the `[ObservableProperty]`. If the content of the collection changes frequently, the collection should also be observable, not just the property, hence the combination of the observable property with the `ObservableCollection`. Technically, it could also be a `List<MyModel>` if only properties of the items change.

Comment: Yes, I mean that ObservableCollection is observable enough as it is. But I am much more interested to know, in what situation you would call "_myitems = something". Am I missing something?

Comment: You would never assign something to `_myItems`, but `MyItems` could be reassigned instead of being cleared. That's also not the point here.

Comment: You can then just use private ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyItems, without annotations.

Comment: No, what I meant is you would never directly reassign the backing field, only via the property. It depends on the use case. I usually make the collection property observable as well, because it may be reassigned to a different collection, e.g. when pulling data from an API, while it may also be altered in-place. There's no need to debate this, it's not at all the point here.